# Complex find statement, don't know how to write multiple values for one condition

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I am trying to build a paginated find call to my Unit model.  I need the condition to be that it looks for unit.type of condo and rentalco, house and rentalco, but NOT rentalco and hotel.  Additionally, the way I have my code worded, cake only returns unit types that are rentalco.

```
public function view($type=null) {
$this->set('title', 'All '.$type.' in and near Gulf Shores');
$this->set('featured', $this->Unit->getFeatured());
$this->paginate['Unit']=array(
        'limit'=>9,
        'order' => 'RAND()',
        'contain'=>array(
                'User'=>array('id'),
                'Location',
                'Complex',
                'Image'
                    ),
        'conditions'=>array(
                'Unit.type'=>array($type, 'rentalco'),
                'Unit.active'=>1)   
    );
   $data = $this->paginate('Unit');
   $this->set('allaccommodations', $data);
$this->set('type', $type);
}
```

**UPDATE** I figured out why my find statement wasn't working (just had been passing the word condos instead of condo into my browser bar....derp derp); however, I would still love to know how I can tell cake to NOT allow a find with both type hotel and rentalco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the NOT. It would be something like:

```
'conditions' => array(
    'NOT' => array('Unit.type' => array('hotel', 'rentalco')),
),
```

To be more specific, I would need to see your model schema.

Comment: That worked.  I had seen the NOT statement in the manual but I didn't realize that it would work as a 'not these two together' option.  Thank you!